# Different acronym \acs color inside mdframed environment

Tags: pdftex, color, mdframed, acronyms

I am using `acronym` and `mdframed` packages and I when I use `\acs{}` inside of `\begin{mdframed}[style=question]` and `\end{mdframed}` I want it to have color "white". How can this be achieved?

---

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=linkcolor,
    citecolor=linkcolor,
    filecolor=linkcolor,
    urlcolor=linkcolor
}


\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{RGB}{77,152,183}
\definecolor{questioncolor}{RGB}{179,179,179}
\definecolor{wantedcolor}{RGB}{180,190,0}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{vprasanje}{%
    font=\normalsize,
    linecolor=questioncolor,
    outerlinewidth=0pt,
    roundcorner=2pt,
    innertopmargin=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=4pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    backgroundcolor=questioncolor}

\begin{document}

\section{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{UL}{University of Ljubljana}
\end{acronym}

\section{Random section}

\begin{mdframed}[style=vprasanje]
I want this acronym \acs{UL} to have different color than the one outside the mdframed environment. Perferably I want this one to have color defined above as "wantedcolor".
\end{mdframed}

I am outside of the invironment \acs{UL}!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Example, please?

Comment: I added the minimal example you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the many options of `\mdfdefinestyle` there is `settings`, which (quote from manual)

> allows the user to commit some macros at the beginning of mdframed.
>   The given material is executed before the savebox starts.

You can use this to locally redefine the linkcolor.

```
\mdfdefinestyle{vprasanje}{%
    font=\normalsize,
    linecolor=questioncolor,
    outerlinewidth=0pt,
    roundcorner=2pt,
    innertopmargin=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=4pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    backgroundcolor=questioncolor,
    settings={\definecolor{linkcolor}{RGB}{180,190,0}}}% <-- add this line
```